# Very Tricky removing erroneous tags whilst grouping by multiple fields in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking to groupby several columns if the prefix is similar and take the sum based off of categorical values within a column.

**Data**

```
name      type    size   month
AA:3400            5     august
AA:3401   FALSE    1     august
AA:3402   FALSE    2     august
AA:3404   TRUE     0     august
AA:3409   FALSE    1     september
AA:3410   FALSE    8     september
AA:3412   FALSE    9     september
BB:3400   TRUE     4     august
BB:3401   FALSE    7     august
```

**Desired**

```
name    type    size  month
AA      TRUE    0     august
AA      FALSE   3     august
AA              5     august
BB      TRUE    4     august
BB      FALSE   7     august
AA      TRUE    0     september
AA      FALSE   18    september
```

**Doing**

However, how can I group if the value has the same prefix? Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
  out = (
    df.assign(type= df["name"].astype(
        pd.CategoricalDtype(["TRUE", "FALSE"], ordered=True)))
      .groupby([df["name", "date"].str.split(":").str[0], "type"],
               dropna=False, group_keys=False)["size"].sum().reset_index()
)
```

However, I am not sure how to incorporate multiple fields in this grouping. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
out = df.groupby([df["name"].str.split(":").str[0],
                  df['month'],
                  df['type']])['size'].sum().unstack('type',fill_value=0).stack().reset_index(name='size')
Out[61]: 
  name      month   type  size
0   AA     august  FALSE     3
1   AA     august   None     5
2   AA     august   TRUE     0
3   AA  september  FALSE    18
4   AA  september   None     0
5   AA  september   TRUE     0
6   BB     august  FALSE     7
7   BB     august   None     0
8   BB     august   TRUE     4
```